# ISTIO service mesh for internal kube services

Tags: istio

I am new to istio and was trying to set it up.

I have a question though: Is istio only meant for traffic coming in to the kube cluster via ingress or can it be used to communicate with services running inside the same kube cluster?

Sorry if it is a noob question, but i am unable to find it anywhere else. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what i have:
1. 2 different versions of a service deployed on the istio mesh:

```
kubectl get pods -n turbo -l component=rhea
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rhea-api-istio-1-58b957dd4b-cdn54   2/2     Running   0          46h
rhea-api-istio-2-5787d4ffd4-bfwwk   2/2     Running   0          46h
```

2. Another service deployed on the istio mesh:

```
kubectl get pods -n saudagar | grep readonly
saudagar-readonly-7d75c5c7d6-zvhz9   2/2     Running   0          5d
```

3. I have a kube service defined like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rhea
  labels:
    component: rhea
  namespace: turbo
spec:
  selector:
    component: rhea
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
    protocol: TCP
```

4. Destination rules:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: rhea
spec:
  host: rhea
  subsets:
  - name: v1
    labels:
      app: rhea-api-istio-1
  - name: v2
    labels:
      app: rhea-api-istio-2
```

5. A virtual service like:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: rhea
  namespace: turbo
spec:
  hosts:
  - rhea
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: rhea
        subset: v1
```

What i am trying to test is circuit breaking, between rhea and saudagar, and traffic routing over the 2 versions of the service.

I want to test this from inside the same kube cluster. I am not able to achieve this. If i want to access rhea service from the saudagar service, what endpoint should i use so that i can see the traffic routing policy applied?

Answer (score 0):

Istio can be used for controlling [ingress traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/) (from outside into the cluster), for controlling [in-cluster traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/) (between services inside the cluster) and for controlling [egress traffic](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/) (from the services inside the cluster to services outside the cluster).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you point me towards some documentation as to how i can use it to control in-cluster traffic? I am not sure how to use the virtual services / gateway / destination rules for in-cluster traffic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer - added links to the relevant sections on istio.io

Comment: I have gone through those sections of the documentation. So if i define a virtual service and access a kube service normally those rules should apply? And will the rules apply if i originate the traffic from within cluster but from a pod outside the istio mesh?

Comment: Basically I am not able to figure out what endpoint should i call for internal services so that i can see the rules in action. If you want i can share my manifests with you...

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got caught up with work. I have updated my questions with details. Could you please help check?

Comment: Hey... Have you had a chance to look at this?

Comment: With Istio you should access the services in the same way as you access them without Istio: in your case by using `rhea` hostname when called from `turbo` namespace, or by using `rhea.turbo` hostname when called from other namespaces. To be on the same size, you can always use the full hostname, `rhea.turbo.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: And in general, I would recommend you to start with https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/ example. It uses Istio to control both ingress traffic and the traffic between services inside a cluster. You can check the code of the services and see how they call each other, check the logs, and in general play with the example which is rather simple.

Comment: RIght. Somehow doesnt seem to be working for me. Guess i will give it a fresh look soon. Thanks for all your help. I will get back to this thread if something changes.

Comment: @IshanDatt I know this is old but did you manage to have two in cluster grpc services communicate?

Comment: @nkigen not yet. Its still work in progress for me. Since it was taking time, i am working on some other priority stuff. I will sure update here once i get to somewhere.